# Back button it is not taking me to previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery load is working but when I press back button it is not taking me to previous page.

This is the code.

```
function openPage(url) {

    if(timer != null){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    if(url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        url = url + "?";
    }

var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn);
    console.log(encodedUrl);
    $("#mainContent").load(encodedUrl);
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
}
```

And the span that opens the page is

```
<span role="link" tabindex="0" onclick="openPage('yourMusic.php')" class="navItemLink">Your Music</span>
```

The problem is when I click the browser back button the url in the address bar changes but the content is not loading in the the '#mainContent' div.

Comment: Did you do anything to instruct the browser to load the previous content back into the div? it isn't magic

Comment: how can i load the previous content back into the div? thanks in advance :-)

Comment: $.load could do it

Answer (score -1):

I ran into something similar and it was due to ajax caching being set to true. Try using jQuery ajax instead and set cache to false...

```
$.ajax({
    url: encodedUrl,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#mainContent").html(data);
    }
});
```

**Oops**

That's actually depricated. Use this instead...

```
$.ajax({
  url: encodedUrl,
  cache: false
})
.done(function( html ) {
    $( "#mainContent" ).append( html );
});
```

Comment: eh, no, actually, that's not deprecated.

Comment: pardon em moi :-) "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `.success` is different from `success:`. Very common misunderstanding.

Comment: Note how that notice says they were "removed" in 3.0, but even in 3.1 that particular one is alive and well, while `.success` is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote @KevinB for the perfectly acceptable code sample. Or samples as you point out since my first example also works.

Comment: My downvote is because the answer is simply wrong. The OP's code doesn't re-request the old content when the back button is pressed. In fact, nothing happens when the back button is pressed other than the url changing back. It isn't because the ajax is cached, it's because no ajax is occuring. Pressing the back button won't call `openPage(thedefaulturl)` or automagically replace the old content in the div.